# Batch get items using Parse API times out

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I have an array of Object Ids which I need to retrieve from Parse.  The size of the array varies greatly, and sometimes there are duplicates.  Up until now, I've been prototyping, so I would use

```
string[] objectIds = new [] { "xT6...
...WhereContainedIn("objectId", objectIds);
```

And this would work okay.  In real life, though, the size of the objectId array above can reach in the hundreds, and the query returns "operation was slow and timed out".  I really have two questions here:

1) There has to be a better way to retrieve an array of objects, if you know the object Ids, but I couldn't find it.  Is WhereContainedIn() the only solution here?

2) Are there any guidelines for how/when queries will simply fail?  The documentation only mentions a limit of 1000 items to be retrieved, and nothing about the query going in.  If it turns out that this query has to be batched, that would be okay, but there are no guidelines for batching, either.

Answer (score 0):

So I have never used (or even heard of parse but reading throught the documentation I found this text about the limit maybe it would help.

"You can limit the number of results by calling Limit. By default, results are limited to 100, but anything from 1 to 1000 is a valid limit:"

https://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#queries-constraints

Comment: Yeah, that's where I got my documentation limit comment from. It doesn't seem to matter.